# Using JavaScript Variables in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

I'm trying to make a YouTube 2.0 html thing, (interesting learning experience). I want it to be so that you click on the "load video" link and it asks you the link to the actual youtube video. Then, when you paste it in, it displays the video on the page.

My code is

```html
<h1 style="background-color: red; color: white; font-family: helvetica; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">Youtube 2.0</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="openVideo()">Load video</a>
<script>
 var theVideoLink;
 
 var openVideo = function() {
  var videoLink = prompt("Video link on YouTube.com");
  theVideoLink = videoLink;
 };
 
 window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML=theVideoLink;
 }
</script>

<iframe width="1120" height="630" src="myLink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you have any ideas on how I can insert the JavaScript variable into my iframe src tag, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Youtube 2.0. ? What's *2.0.-ish* in your code? Also, if you're referring to https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol than my question is: have you opened that page?

Comment: It's not actually YouTube 2.0. I just called it that. It's not a buisness project, I was just messing around.

Comment: `width="1120"`...Don't. Welcome to the responsive era. Use CSS stylesheet, use `%` or other responsive units. Avoid using inline `style`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change iframe src but we can replace your iframe with new one.

Note, I have set your iframe ID as myLink, replacing the src attribute.

```
<h1 style="background-color: red; color: white; font-family: helvetica; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">Youtube 2.0</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="openVideo()">Load video</a>

<iframe width="1120" height="630" id="myLink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
openVideo = function() {
  var videoLink = prompt("Video link on YouTube.com");
  var iframe=document.getElementById('myLink');

  var new_iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        new_iframe.src=videoLink;

  let attr;
  let attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(iframe.attributes);
  while(attr = attributes.pop()) {
    if (attr.nodeName!='src')
        new_iframe.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
  }

  iframe.parentNode.replaceChild(new_iframe, iframe);
}
</script>
```

Make sure to embed the embed link, in this format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/MEVYajbHmb4
```

Working JS fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/aa0kzqsz/2/

Comment: Updated the answer once again so that it doesn't get stuck when loading multiple videos.

Answer (score 0):

This code navigates the `<iframe>` to URL that typed in prompt dialog.

```
<h1 style="background-color: red; color: white; font-family: helvetica; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">Youtube 2.0</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="openVideo()">Load video</a>
<script>

var openVideo = function() {
    var videoLink = prompt("Video link on YouTube.com");
    window.open(videoLink, "myLink");
}
```

```
<iframe width="1120" height="630" name="myLink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Update**: This code only navigates `<iframe>` to given URL. You should probably use Youtube embed options instead of this.

Comment: Wont work with multiple videos due to same origin policy.

Comment: Yes, I will add this info. But he asks how to navigate iframe with js code. I just answered that question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the iframe is wrong. You need to specify "myLink" as *id* not as *src*.

Then you need to transform the youtube link (which is like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoId}") into the iframe link (which is like "https://www.youtube.com/embed/{videoId}"). To achieve this you need to learn about regexp. The following will work:

```js
var ytLink = prompt('Give me a youtube link please !');
var iframe = document.getElementById('youtube');
var ytId   = ytLink.match(/v=([-A-Za-z]+)/)[1];

iframe.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + ytId;
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" id="youtube" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I recommend you to learn more about regex on the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: you should check your `ytId` before doing `[1]`

Comment: Good point about transforming the embed link, but you can't change src of an iframe due to same origin policy.

Comment: This is a simple code working only for the specific case you enter an attempted URL. If you use it you obviously need more checks. Also, I don't recommend to use a prompt. This is only for demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You must use embed link instead of full link

like: https://www.youtube.com/embed/`videoID`

```js
 
 var openVideo = function() {
  var videoID = prompt("Video id on YouTube.com");
    var embed = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'
  document.getElementById("myFrame").src=embed+videoID;
 };
```

```html
<h1 style="background-color: red; color: white; font-family: helvetica; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">Youtube 2.0</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="openVideo()">Load video</a>


<iframe id=myFrame width="1120" height="630" src=# frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't change src of an iframe due to same origin policy.

Comment: you can when using embed link, just try with this id  `ZYlG9Id9H5s` . and can you please remove your -1